# Prevent Exceeding Maximum Recursion Depth

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to make a small script and an efficient way of doing it involves calling a function within itself. However, this gives the message "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object".

I tried to cause to program to exit before it reached this, but it does not seem to do the job. I'm wondering if there is any way to stop a program after a certain number of runs so this error does not happen. Here is what I tried to do to fix this:

```
import sys
n = 0
def cycle(b,n):
    total = 0
    for i in str(n):
        for y in i:
         total+=int(y)**b
    n+=1
    print(total)
    if n == 10:
     sys.exit()
    else:
     cycle(b,total)
cycle(2,562)
```

Thanks.

Comment: *"recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object"* suggests that the error isn't in the code you've shown. Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why doesn't the function return anything? Note also that the `n` inside the function isn't the same as the `n` you set to zero.

Comment: Why do you assign `n = 0` at the top and then not do anything with it? What's the point of `for y in i` when `i` is already a single character?

Comment: I think you are more likely to see progress if you could let us know what the point of this computation is.

Comment: @user1956027, your logic is incorrect not the  recursion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing in a counter and avoid giving confusing variable names:

```
import sys
def cycle(b,n, counter):
    total = 0
    for i in str(n):
        for y in i:
         total+=int(y)**b
    counter+=1
    print(total)
    if counter == 10:
     sys.exit()
    else:
     cycle(b,total,counter)
cycle(2,562,0)
```

[Run it here.](https://repl.it/qMW/1)

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was trying to do with n = 0 but it seems it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Calling a function recursively might be convenient, but certainly not efficient (at least with the implementation of python you're using, since you get this error).

Yet, what you're trying to do, i.e. limit the recursion depth, is already what happens since you get a runtime error related to the recursion depth.

Why don't you just catch that runtime error at a higher level ?

Answer (score 0):

Happy numbers (which is what you're doing there) either [end in 1 or end up in the cycle 4, 16, 37, 58, 89, 145, 42, 20, 4, ...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_number#Sequence_behavior). So just stop when you reach 1 or 4. Though in general, if your recursion is too deep, you ought to consider an iterative solution.

Comment: I know I could of done that but I felt like that was cheating, I wanted this to work regardless of the cycle of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return and use a proper base case:

```
def cycle(b, n, seen):
    total = 0
    if n == 1 or n in seen:
        return n == 1
    for i in str(n):
        for y in i:
            total += int(y) ** b
    seen.add(n)
    n += 1
    return cycle(b, total, seen)


print(cycle(2, 19,set()))
```

Output:

```
In [34]: cycle(2,562,set())
Out[34]: False

In [35]: cycle(2,19,set())
Out[35]: True

In [36]: cycle(2,1,set())
Out[36]: True

In [37]: cycle(2,2,set())
Out[37]: False

In [38]: cycle(2,7,set())
Out[38]: True
```